# sklearn Countervectorizer use self-defined tokenizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

An example:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'x':['thisisanewveaddea','sklearnisbeautiful']})
#transfer to list
df1=list(df.x.values)
from sklearn.feature_extraction import text
vectorizer=text.CountVectorizer()
x=vectorizer.fit_transform(df1)
x.toarray()
```

The word vector is :

```
Out[105]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

The tokenizer is :

```
vectorizer.get_feature_names()
Out[106]: ['sklearnisbeautiful', 'thisisanewveaddea']
```

However, I want to use my own tokenizer/dictionary:

```
mydict=['thisi','san','ewveaddea','sklearnisb','eautiful']
```

With my own tokenizer,the expected word vector is:

```
 x                ['thisi','san','ewveaddea','sklearnisb','eautiful']

'thisisanewveaddea':[1,      1,       1,           0,         0]
'sklearnisbeautiful':[0,     0,       0,           1          1]
```

How do I transfer my own tokenizer to sklearn's `Countervectorizer`

Answer (score 0):

`CountVectorizer` has a `tokenizer` parameter where you can pass your custom tokenizer.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html